# How to combine Legend Values of existing LULC in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, legend, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, land-classification

I'm trying to refer my study area with this amazing [LULC](https://glad.earthengine.app/view/global-land-cover-land-use-v1), I found on Earth Engine Apps, but it has about 255 legend values. I am not understanding how to proceed with this classification of my study area with this LULC. How should I proceed with it?

Solution(I think): By combining the legend values. But Is it possible to combine the legend values on GEE?

I have no clue. I'm a new learner and want to know how to go with this.

Answer (score 0):

You have the [`ee.Image.remap()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-remap) method, though it can be quite tedious to remap 255 classes using this approach. If you're having consecutive ranges of input values that map to a single output value, you could perhaps do something like the below. It save you some space/time, and lower the risk of introducing errors in the mapping:

```
var map = ee.ImageCollection('projects/glad/GLCmap2019').mosaic()

// Definition on how to remap
var remappings = [
  {from: 0, to: 5, value: 1}, // Values 0-5 (inclusive) map to 1.
  {from: 6, to: 37, value: 2},
  {from: 38, to: 50, value: 3}
]

var remapped = remap(map, remappings)


function remap(image, remappings) {
  var lookupIn = ee.List([])
  var lookupOut = ee.List([])
  remappings.map(function (remapping) {
    lookupIn = lookupIn.cat(
      ee.List.sequence(remapping.from, remapping.to)
    )
    lookupOut = lookupOut.cat(
      ee.List.repeat(remapping.value, 1 + remapping.to - remapping.from)
    )
  })
  return image.remap(lookupIn, lookupOut)
}

Map.addLayer(map, null, 'map')
Map.addLayer(remapped, null, 'remapped')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8026975f3bc5011d2dfced7460903d3a